# Standard json ld package with all (generated) java objects from schema.org

Tags: java, json, database, pojo, json-ld

I've just started a project where I try to use schema definitions from schema.org like https://schema.org/PostalAddress as a blue print for classes and database tables.

It's not straight forward with multiple inheritance hierarchy. And it's a boring task to implement the code, since I expect there should be a default implementation in java (and other languages). And simple wrapper for untyped data like https://github.com/google/schemaorg-java are not helpful for the use case.

Is there a java library where all the definitions from schema.org are included as pojos out of the box?

I've looked around but just found generators like https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo, validator or serialization/deserialization tools.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.
Did you find ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created a library to generate Java classes from the schema definitions.

https://github.com/Kobee1203/schema-org-java

It supports inheritance, and different versions of schema, plus other options available.

I made a Maven plugin to generate the classes.

Here is a video that shows how it works:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1423193/199852384-e41869fb-beae-4106-be0f-1482393b9e0c.mp4

I plan to add a module to serialize/deserialize generated Schema.org objects to and from JSON-LD formats.